ESlint doesn't allow to build nextjs 15 app because of unused error variable in a try catch
I'm learning nextJS 15 and I'm making an app using the pokeAPI but when I run npm run build eslint gives me the following message:
Error: 'error' is defined but never used.  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
The following code is the one producing the error:
const getPokemon = async (id: string) => {
    try {
        const pokemon = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}`, {
            cache: "force-cache"
        }).then(res => res.json());
        return pokemon;
    } catch (error) {
        notFound();
    }
};

Is there a way to ignore that unused variable specifically?
Here's the .eslintrc.json:
{
    "extends": ["next/core-web-vitals", "next/typescript"]
}

I tried the no-unused-vars rule but it didn't work

You can simply write the try catch without binding the error to a variable:
try {
  /* ... */
} catch {
  notFound();
}


There are two ways you can go about fixing this

Disable the eslint rule for just that file alone: You can do this by pasting this at the top of the file /* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars */
You can set a disable/turnoff the rule in all the files in your project by adding a rule object to your eslintrc.json file

eslintrc.json
{
    "extends": ["next/core-web-vitals", "next/typescript"],
    "rules":{
     "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "off"
    }
}


You can add other turn-off other eslint rules in this object.
There are a few values you can use, (off or 0), (on or 1), or "warn".
